# Difficulty in using smooth blurred textures in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures

I have planned to use blurred textures as shadow for my planes by just placing them on the surface below it.

In the first image you see below, there are three shadows.
 1. Smiley's shadow: Default-Particle given by Unity and works great for this purpose.
 2. Square: & 3. Arrow: A shape I created are not good enough.

To clarify the exact problem please find the 2nd image I have attached. The shadow(texture) is of very poor quality.

How to get the fine quality in blurred textures?

Image 1: 
[image]

Image 2: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the import settings of your texture asset. This can be done by clicking the texture asset in the Project view. Then in the inspector view you can find "Format" drop down. You probably have either "Compressed" or "16 bit" chosen. If you change it to "Truecolor", the texture should look fine.

[image: Texture import settings]

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It worked.
I have another issue, I have raised this question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28211943/unity3d-transparent-shader-allows-the-objects-below-to-show-on-top?

Please look if you can fix it.